# Server is working, but not able open in browser

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I am trying to use Jquery, I used a command-:
python -m HTTP.server on my Windows PowerShell, server is started but when I trying to use the address http://0.0.0.0:8000 in my browser it is showing an error as follow-
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
my firewall is allowing access.
please help.

Comment: `localhost:8000`?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a real address, it's a special value that means "listen on every IPv4 network you can listen on". To connect, you have to specify one of those addresses. Usually you'll want to use `127.0.0.1` if you're running on the same machine of the server.

Comment: If you are using Django, then you should be using `python manage.py runserver` in development, not `python -m http.server`.

Answer (score 9):

[`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is not a real address; it's a special value that means "listen on every IPv4 network you can listen on".

To connect, you have to specify one of those addresses.

---

If your browser is on the same machine as the server, you want to use the localhost address, like either of the following:

```
http://localhost:8000
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

That [`127.0.0.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is a real address, but it's a special one meaning "the same machine I'm on, without going through the network" (and `localhost` is a special name for that address).

---

If your server is on a different machine from the browser, you have to use an IP address or name that actually maps to the server. For example, if you started the server by doing `ssh 192.168.1.100` and then running it in the shell there, you'll connect like this:

```
http://192.168.1.100:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing the django server (ctrl + c on termial) and then restarting my computer worked for me